# How to define piecewise function for joint CDF

Tags: probability, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose I have $X,Y$, which are continuous random variables, with a joint PDF:
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
    24xy & 0 \leq x \text{ and } 0 \leq y \text{ and } x+y \leq 1 \\
    0 & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$

I want to find the joint CDF, which I have calculated to be $6x^2y^2 $. However, I'm not sure how to define the piecewise function for the joint CDF.

I wrote out the CDF below, but I'm not sure if the cases of $x$ and $y$ are correct for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.
$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \text { or } y < 0\\
6x^2y^2 & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \text{ and } 0 \leq y \leq 1 \text{ and } x+y \leq 1\\
1 & x > 0 \text{ and } y > 0 \text{ and } x+y > 1\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Consider $F_{X,Y}(1,0.01) = P(Y \le 0.01)$.  You can try calculating the marginal distribution function $F_Y(y) = F_{X,Y}(1,y)$ to see that your answer is wrong.

Comment: The 3rd case: make a sketch of the region and you'll see.

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose : now  you corrected the density but the rest is wrong...wronger than before

Comment: @tommik Sorry I forgot to correct the cdf. It should be fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following drawing:

[image]

Thus the CDF is the following:

$$F_{XY}(x,y)=6x^2y^2\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(x)\mathbb{1}_{(0;1-x)}(y)+\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(x)\mathbb{1}_{(1-x;\infty)}(y)+\mathbb{1}_{(1;\infty)}(x)\mathbb{1}_{(0;\infty)}(y)$$

---

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose : see my edits

Comment: So I see that you graphed the support. But what do the subscripts in $F_{XY}(x,y)$ mean (i.e. $1_{(0;1)}$ )?

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose : $\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(x)$ is an indicator function. I this case, the indicator function is 1 when $x$ is in the interval subscripted. It is a compact way to express the domain. In your stament I do not see what happens, i.e. when $0<x<1$ and $y<0$

Comment: Oh okay, I get it! Thanks!

Comment: When $0<x<1$ and $y<0$, the cdf should be $0$. Isn't that covered in the "or" case? i.e. cdf is $0$ when $x\leq0$ or $y\leq0$

Comment: @inquisitivemongoose : sorry yes...you are right. I read "and"...my fault

Comment: No worries. Anyways thank you so much! The cdf with the indicator functions really helped! Really appreciate your time to explain everything.